# Override <customErrors mode="Off"/> message from .NET Framework even when in web.config detailed errors are turned on

Tags: iis-7.5, custom-errors

is this possible to override .NET Framework error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

...

<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

even if web.config (IIS7.5) is set to

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>
```

?
I'm asking because my default setting for IIS7 is

```
<deployment retail="true" />
```

so no error is being showed and only adding additional error handling module to website will allow to see errors generated by this application and thats why I want to override this message to inform users about it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's my observation. If you configure httpErrors in IIS 7.5, the error messages are for non .net pages i.e. .htm, .asp, .css. If you want to configure customError messages in IIS 7.5, you will need to configure the same in .NET Error Pages section in IIS 7.5.

With `<deployment retail="true" />`, the configuration is going to take effect on system.web and not on system.webServer and hence httpErrors won't get affected.

Somebody, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yeah, both system.web and system.webServer need to be updated to handle errors for asp.net and non-asp.net.

Additionally, there are other errors that are masked in IIS7 that can be enabled by setting existingResponse to Passthrough: http://serverfault.com/questions/69839/show-php-error-message-on-iis-7