# IIS7 and PHP: Show error messages with all the rest of the output

Tags: php, iis-7, stdout, stderr

Okay, this is slowly getting annoying. I'm used to work with Apache Webservers and never had any of these problems. IIS seems to try to be intelligent - or whatever.

Here's my situation: My customer wants a PHP website and it is supposed to run on an Windows IIS webserver.

For my development environment I could use my Apache - but just to be sure I want to do it with IIS, too. So I set up a dev-server with Windows Vista, all the latest Updates and installed IIS. Everything fine!

I quickly found instructions on how to install PHP in IIS on some official Microsoft site. Modified php.ini - have been doing stuff like that for years on Linux/Apache machines.

So now I have a Server to run IIS on and my workstation which I use to develop, accessing the files on the server over network.

My first "phpinfo()" page - everything okay. Now I intentionally break the page by introducing a bug: All I get on my workstation is "Server Error 500". When I access the page directly on the server I see an PHP error message... Well, got that worked out with [this serverfault.com question](https://serverfault.com/questions/69839/show-php-error-message-on-iis-7).

BUT: It still keeps annoying me: Now if there is an error all I get is JUST the error message. I don't see any of the other output of the script. In fact in Firefox I don't see anything at all in case of an error.

For example if I do this...

```
<?PHP 
$sql = 'THIS WON\'T WORK';
echo $sql;
$DB->exec($sql);  // <- This causes an error
?>
```

all I get is

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function exec() on a non-object in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpinfo.php on line 4
```

What I actually want is that it shows me the output of everything that happened before the error so that I can use that to fix my problem.

How do I get IIS (or PHP?) to show me everything? Error message AND context? Over the network?

**Update**

Okay, I may have a lead. When I go to my console and call my script manually via php-cgi.exe this is what I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function exec() on a non-object in C:\inetpub
\wwwroot\phpinfo.php on line 4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.12
Content-type: text/html

THIS WON'T WORK<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function exec() on a non-object in <b>C:\i
netpub\wwwroot\phpinfo.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```

I then tried to pipe the output to a files and figured out that the first two lines are piped to stderr and the rest goes to stdout ([Read here for more info about that](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)).

I can also see that what I get in my browser is the output to stderr, because it does not contain any HTML formatting.

I can now narrow my question down to this: I have a FastCGI PHP-CGI that outputs an error message to stderr and the page causing the error to stdout. It currently forwards stderr to the browser - how do I get it to use stdout instead?

Answer (score 0):

... and finally I got it working.

Based on my stderr findings I did some more googling and found this document about "[Secure PHP with Configuration Settings](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/secure-php-with-configuration-settings)" on IIS.net.

I have an dev machine, so I don't really need to get it bullet proof, but it still had my  solution:

```
fastcgi.logging=0
```

Put this in your PHP.INI and PHP will stop sending stuff to stderr - et voila: I get my usual PHP output in my browser window!